# Android IR Samsung TV application with the Tools support

Tags: android, remote-access

Which Android IR (remote TV) application supports the `Tools` option for Samsung Smart TV? All the applications I tried support the usual options like:

- Arrows
- OK button
- Menu button
- Channels up and down
- Volume up and down

But none seems to support the `Tools` menu found in All Share application and in Samsung's Smart Hub. I am using Redmi Note 2 phone. Attached is the image of the option I am trying to access via infra red port.
[image]

Comment: Which ones did you try? I'm not sure which supports that, but [here's a list of Samsung TV Remotes](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_mmdevices#group_680), maybe it has one that slipped through your nets.

Comment: Xiaomi Remote, Anymote, and Samsungs' remotes on Google play.